# If a, b are complex numbers then the maximum value of $\dfrac{a\bar b+\bar ab}{|ab|}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

If a, b are complex numbers then the maximum value of $\dfrac{a\bar b+\bar ab}{|ab|}$ is

(A) 2

(B) 1

(C) the expression may not always be a real number and hence maximum does not make sense

(D) none of the above.

My Steps:

Let $a=x+iy$ and $b=p+iq$.

Then $$\begin{align}
\dfrac{a\bar b+\bar ab}{|ab|} &= \dfrac{(x+iy)(p-iq)+(x-iy)(p+iq)}{|(x+iy)(p+iq)|}\\
&= \dfrac{2xp+2yq}{(xp-yq)^2+(xq+yp)^2}
\end{align}$$

If I take $y=q=0$ and $x=p=1/n$, the maximum value can be taken to $\infty$.

So, is the answer option D ?

Please advise.

Comment: $z+\bar{z}=2\Re{z}$ and $\Re{z}/|z|\leq 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error in your expansion.

$$|ab|=\sqrt{(xp - yq)^2+(xq+yp)^2}$$

Using your choice here of real values for $a$ and $b$, this gives $2xp/(xp)=2$.

Comment: I hope I won't forget the absolute value formula again ..Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Hint:
$$ \dfrac{a\bar{b}+\bar{a}b}{|ab|}=\dfrac{2\Re(\bar{a}b)}{|\bar{a}b|}\leq 2$$